# Db2 stored procedure to increment a column value for a certain unique combination

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

Db2 stored procedure to increment a column value for a certain unique combination.

I want to write a DB2 stored procedure where `SEQ_I` is a column value that should only be incremented for a single combination of the column values (`SCHOOL_I, DEPT_I`, and `LIST_I`).

In my below procedure, I want to use the `max(SEQ_I) + 1` for school, dept, and list combo

`SCHOOL_I, DEPT_I, LIST_I` and `SEQ_I` are columns of a table `SCHOOL_DEPT`

I tried writing it the below way. Please guide.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CREATE_PCT_OFF_SUPPLIER  
        (IN IN_SCHOOL_I INTEGER
        ,IN IN_DEPT_I CHAR(6)
        ,IN IN_LIST_I INTEGER
        ,IN IN_SEQ_I SMALLINT)
P1: BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS COMB FROM SCHOOL_DEPT
        WHERE SCHOOL_I= IN_SCHOOL_I AND DEPT_I=IN_DEPT_I AND LIST_I = IN_LIST_I;

        IF COMB = 1 THEN  
        INSERT INTO SCHOOL_DEPT(SCHOOL_I,DEPT_I, LIST_I,SEQ_I) VALUES (IN_SCHOOL_I, IN_DEPT_I, _IN_LIST_I, MAX(IN_SEQ_I)+1); 
        ELSE
        INSERT INTO SCHOOL_DEPT(SCHOOL_I,DEPT_I, LIST_I) VALUES (IN_SCHOOL_I, IN_DEPT_I, _IN_LIST_I); 
END P1
```

Comment: ...why do you (think you) need a partitioned sequence?  Are there other constraints - gapless, automatic rollback, or what?  What does the sequence value represent?

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you are doing to do does not match what your stored procedure does. It will add columns not increment a value. To increment a value, then you need to use the update statement, e.g.

```
update SCHOOL_DEPT
set SEQ_I=SEQ_I+1
where SCHOOL_I= IN_SCHOOL_I AND DEPT_I=IN_DEPT_I AND LIST_I = IN_LIST_I;
```

What you are doing is adding a record if you find exactly one record that matches the combination of school, department, and list and add a record with `SEQ_I` with `IN_SEQ_I+1`. Not sure why you are calculating the max of a single number (not even sure if the max function can be used this way). In addition to that you add a record if the combination is not found or found more than once without setting `SEQ_I`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me :

```
DECLARE SEQ SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 ;

SELECT MAX(SEQ_I)+1 INTO SEQ FROM FROM SCHOOL_DEPT
    WHERE SCHOOL_I= IN_SCHOOL_I AND DEPT_I=IN_DEPT_I AND LIST_I = IN_LIST_I;

IF SEQ IS NULL THEN 
    SET SEQ = 1; 
END IF;
```